# Custom Exception handling across multiple API Controllers in different Apps (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a central application that speaks to multiple other applications via a controller.
Let's say that controller A (source) reaches out to Controller B for some data. At present, we return the data, and only the data (no timestamps, no user details, etc)

***App 1: Controller A***

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ExpectedType>> GetData(ModelType model)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _dataFetchingBizLayer.GetThatDataFromApp2(model);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Log(ex);
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message); // "There was an issue."
    }
}
```

***App 1: The _dataFetchingBizLayer (business logic layer)***

```
 public async Task<ExpectedType> GetThatDataFromApp2(ModelType model)
 {
     var response = await _secondaryAppWrapper.GetThatData(
         new QueryModelType
         {
            //... shape the query data object
         });

     return response;
 }
```

***App 2: Controller B***

```
public ActionResult<ExpectedType> GetThatData(QueryModelType model)
{
    try
    {
        var response = _dataFetchingDAO.GetDataFromDB(model);
        return response;
    }
    catch (CustomException customEx)
    {
        _logger.Log(customEx);
        return StatusCode(500, customEx.Message); // "The error occurred at station B."
    }
}
```

With that said, Controller B has been written to include some custom exceptions that are thrown throughout various parts of the system where applicable.
Unfortunately, when the Custom Exception is thrown in Controller B and returned, the exception seen in Controller A does not contain that custom message. Rather it outputs its own message as seen above.

I was able to find a workaround for this by using `APIException` in Controller A to catch the exceptions thrown by Controller B. I also have to update the return value for Controller B to return `ex.Response` and not `ex.Message`.

*In Controller A:*

```
catch (APIException apiEx)
{
    _logger.Log(apiEx);
    return StatusCode(500, apiEx.Response);
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way for to transmit the custom message and status codes, along with catching the other exception types sent from Controller B into Controller A.

I am unsure if this is a viable solution long-term and I'm currently toying with the idea of creating custom response classes as a better solution.

Please let me know if there is any additional information needed.

Comment: Are you controllers in the same app? Or are they in different apps, and you're making an HTTP call from one to the other?

Comment: It is not clear what your app does. There are two distinct names for your data layer - `_dataFetchingDao` and `_dataFetchingBizLogic`. Are these in the same project, running in the same process, or are these two different deployments that talk via HTTP?
What happens in `_dataFetchingDao` if it receives that StatusCode object?

Comment: @mason Apologies for not clarifying enough. Yes each of the controllers are in different apps.

Comment: @StenPetrov Each of the controllers are in separate Apps. They talk via HTTP.

I have the two switched, apologies.
The mock Business Logic class makes the call to the App with Controller B, and there it makes the call to the DAO for the actual data.

I have updated my question with examples of the business logic layer. The DAO would utilize entity framework to access a sql DB.

Comment: the order is irrelevant, but don't expect an exception to somehow fly over the HTTP call.
on the caller end you can check if the response status code is 500 and use the response content, which should be the exception message emitted on the receiving end.

Comment: @StenPetrov Thank you. I was able to resolve this by utilizing the APIException type on the catch.

catch (APIException ex)
{
      return StatusCode(400, ex.Response);
}

This allows for the exception being thrown from the secondary API controller, to be sent and accessed by the primary API Controller.
Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this by catching APIException in Controller A to catch the exceptions thrown by Controller B.

Message Sent from Controller B:

```
catch (CustomExceptionType customEx)
    {
        _logger.Log(customEx);
        return StatusCode(400, customEx.Message); // 'Bad data found here'
    }
```

Exception caught in Controller A:

```
catch (APIException apiEx)
{
    _logger.Log(apiEx);
    return StatusCode(apiEx, apiEx.Response); // apiEx.Response = 'Bad data found here'
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Log(ex);
    return StatusCode(500, ex.Message) // ex.Message = stringified custom exception
}
```

In the above code, the ex.Message was found to contain a stringified object containing 'StatusCode: 400 and Response: Bad data found here'

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this call **_dataFetchingBizLogic.GetDataFromDB(model);** directly in Controller A, then catch your CustomException in Controller A also.

Consider not coupling the controllers on each others, this is a bad design.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. The separation is required as mutliple other apps also access the Controller B functions.

Otherwise, we'd definitely do this. :)